# using multiple columns css from left to right, instead of top to bottom

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress, multiple-columns

I'm using on a page on my website on wordpress,  css columns to display some content from its children page.
all my page titles are displayed in 2 colums, alpahbeticaly.

like this :

Column 1     | Column 2

Page Title A | Page Title F

Page Title B | Page Title G

Page Title C | Page Title H

Page Title D | Page Title I

Page Title E | Page Title J

here is my html and php :

```
<div class="column_artists_menu">

            <?php

            $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'page',     
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'orderby'        => 'title',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            );

            $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>



            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>



                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

and my CSS :

```
.column_artists_menu{
-moz-column-width: 50%;
-webkit-column-width: 50%;
-o-column-width: 50%;
column-width: 50%;
-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-o-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 20px;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
-o-column-gap: 20px;
column-gap: 20px;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;
-webkit-column-rule-color: #eeeeee;
-webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
-moz-column-rule-width: 1px;
-moz-column-rule-color: #eeeeee;
-moz-column-rule-style: solid;
-o-column-rule-width: 1px;
-o-column-rule-color: #eeeeee;
-o-column-rule-style: solid;
column-rule-width: 1px;
column-rule-color: #eeeeee;
column-rule-style: solid;
}
```

it works perfectly.
but my pages are sorted from top to bottom, like in the table above.
what I would like to do is to get my pages title displayed like this, from left to right.

Column 1     | Column 2

Page Title A | Page Title B

Page Title C | Page Title D

Page Title E | Page Title F

Page Title G | Page Title H

Page Title I | Page Title J

is there a way to do it and use the css column wich are very useful ?

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Do you have an online example? This should work but it sounds like you have other rules interfering. You could also disable the column width and the border temporarily to see if that causes problems as the sum of all widths is more than 100%.

Comment: I am not sure columns are the right solution here. Why not using a simple html `table` here? Or Just `span`s that line breaks every second element?

Answer (score 0):

thanks you all for your reply, but I know how to use table... ;-)

the point is that I wanted to use column to have a border and a a gap between the two column, but not on the right of the second column. I've found another solution with float left, border-right, and :nth-child(even) with no border.
here is my code if anyone needs :

```
.div1{
width: 470px;
float: left;
padding-right: 9px;
border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;}

.div1:nth-child(even){padding-right: 0px;
border-right: none;padding-left: 10px}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use CSS3 columns for this layout. For example, use "rows" instead:

```
<style>
.row > div {
    float: left;
}
</style>

<div class=“row”>
    <div>
        <h2>Page Title A</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Page Title B</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div>
        <h2>Page Title C</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Page Title D</h2>
    </div>  
</div>
```